¿Cómo codificar IPs v4 y v6 en tipo float en python sin añadir sesgo a una red neuronal?
Tengo un dataset de tráfico IoT (ToN_IoT datasets) donde las columnas con las IPs de origen y destino son cadenas (me las detecta como object). Necesito convertirlas a tipo float para pasarlas a una red neuronal para entrenarla y quería preguntar por cómo codificar estas IPs, tanto v4 como v6, de forma que no añadan un sesgo al modelo. Había pensado en añadir 128 caracteristicas al dataset (aunque parezcan muchas son menos de las mas de 30mil que obtengo al aplicar one-hot, lo cual es inviable y encima no permitirá que la red generalice bien después) en las que se representan cada uno de los bits de las direcciones, para el caso de las IPv4 tendrían las primeras columnas de bits a 0 y los últimos 32 se coreresponderían con la IPv4. No se si esta es la mejor forma de codificar direcciones IP para entrenar una red, ni tengo muy claro como hacerlo.
En resumen, ¿esta es la mejor forma de codificar direcciones?, y, ¿cómo podría hacer esto en python de forma eficiente? (El dataset es bastante grande y me gustaría usar la mayor parte posible del mismo)
Muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

En Python los float ocupan 8 bytes (64 bits). Una dirección IPv6 tiene 128 bits, por lo que no puedes representarlas con float. Por otra parte, las direcciones IP son enteros de 32/128 bits, que Python puede manejar perfectamente.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Dependiendo del dataset y su distribución, ( x ej son todas ipes locales? estan la mayoría en los mismos bloques? ) se me ocurre que un hash rápido de 32bits puede servir.
Igualmente podes hacer un analisis previo a ver cuantas colisiones hay y descartar bits, o encontrar lower y upper bounds, consideras el lower 0 , el upper 1 , matemagiqueas las ip y ahí tenes un "float".
import zlib
ipv4 = '192.168.0.1'
crc4 = zlib.crc32(ipv4.encode())
f4 = float(f'0.{crc4}')
print(f'ipv4 {ipv4} | crc32 {crc4} | float {f4}')

ipv4 = '192.168.0.2'
crc4 = zlib.crc32(ipv4.encode())
f4 = float(f'0.{crc4}')
print(f'ipv4 {ipv4} | crc32 {crc4} | float {f4}')

ipv6 = '2606:4700:4700::1111'
crc6 = zlib.crc32(ipv6.encode())
f6 = float(f'0.{crc6}')
print(f'ipv6 {ipv6} | crc32 {crc6} | float {f6}')

ipv6 = '2606:4700:4700::1001'
crc6 = zlib.crc32(ipv6.encode())
f6 = float(f'0.{crc6}')
print(f'ipv6 {ipv6} | crc32 {crc6} | float {f6}')

ipv4 192.168.0.1 | crc32 2307365224 | float 0.2307365224
ipv4 192.168.0.2 | crc32 277792978 | float 0.277792978
ipv6 2606:4700:4700::1111 | crc32 2630704974 | float 0.2630704974
ipv6 2606:4700:4700::1001 | crc32 2215904312 | float 0.2215904312



Un hash más simple es ir poniendo las IP en una lista, y usar la posición como valor de hash.

Sería un hash sin colisiones.

Sep, aunque por temas de memoria tal vez sea mejor el índice de una db onda pk autoincrement unique sarasa
